# Fancybox 2 change z-index after load

Tags: jquery, fancybox, z-index, fancybox-2

Im using fancybox 2 - and after it has been loaded I want to make several divs "appear" when clicked on a button. With appear I mean change the z-index to something over 8030 (which is the default for fancybox). But it doesnt work as expected. I see the z-index gets applied - but it is still behind the black overlay.

Edit: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8dWa/17/

**Solution:** position:relative

Css:

```
.inline_div{
    display:none;
}
.first{
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed:
        top:1;
    left:1;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
}
#m_help{
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
    background:white;
    color:#888;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
    margin:5px 0 5px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="first">
    <a href="#help_overlay" class="inline_helper" id="m_help">Show Box</a>
    <div id="help_overlay" class="inline_div">
        <h1>It works!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fancybox:

```
$(".inline_helper").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 500,
    maxHeight   : 500,
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    scrolling   : false,
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    openSpeed   : 150,

    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeSpeed  : 150

});
```

Button click:

```
$('#m_help').click(function(){
    $('#m_help').css('z-index','8050');
});
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to #m_help solves it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8dWa/17/

Answer (score 0):

Add Some more value like:

```
$('#m_help').click(function(){
    $('#m_help').css('z-index','10000');
});
```

Also please inspect z-index using Firebug to make your div visible.

Comment: Already tried that - doesnt matter how high or low the z-index, it is always behind the black layer.

Comment: you can hide that black overlay.inspect that layer and hide it using its class etc.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle and updated the code - it seems it has something to do with the css of the parent. It works without it.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8dWa/16/

Changed the #m_help to `position:fixed`. then it works... needs some beautify but it works.

Comment: Yes, and this is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Let the LINK shine through the overlay after it was clicked.